# Space between a paragraph and multicol environment

Tags: spacing, enumerate, multicol

I tried to use `\noindent` and `\tolerance` to get no space between the paragraph and the items from the list, but I have no success. Is there another way to change that?

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item List
  \begin{multicols}{3}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item 1
      \item 2
      \item 3
      \item 4
      \item 5
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Comment: I also tried \vspace{-.25cm} for example, but I want something more fancy.

Comment: Are you sure you want a vertical enumeration?

Comment: @Bernard what do you mean? haha

Comment: The usual first line should be `(a) 1    (b) 2   (c) 3`.

Comment: @Bernard yes, but I don't know how to change it hahaha is there a command?

Comment: There are the `shortlst` or the ` tasks` packages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it with `tasks`. Adjust the value of `item-indent` to your real needs. Also remove the `[showframe]` option of `geometry` for production : it's only there to check the margins are OK:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item List\leavevmode\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep}
  \begin{tasks}[counter-format = (tsk[a]), item-indent = 2cm, label-width = 1.5em](3)
      \task 1
      \task 2
      \task 3
      \task 4
      \task 5
    \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document} %
```

[image]

Comment: Why this downvote?